# jquery - Change text upon writing

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html input field with an Id. There is also some empty div in another part of the page. What I want to do is to copy the text AS PER WRITING in the input field. The very same as this site does upon creating a question. (Note the textarea you type in, and the part below it -- this is the exact functionality i want).

I want to use jQuery for this. What function?

Answer (score 3):

On keyup function will do this.

```
$("#myinput").keyup(
    function(){
        my_text = $(this).val(); // grab what's in the field
        // do stuff with the text so that it's what you want
        $("#other_div").val(my_text);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myInputField").keydown(function(){
  $("#myDiv").html($(this).val());
})
```

try this

Comment: Should I put this in .live or .on or something? to BIND ?

Comment: unless the field is dynamically loaded through js this should be fine

Answer (score 0):

It is better to try with keyup because if you use keydown you will loose the last character.

```
$("#myInputField").keyup(function(){
   $("#myDiv").html($(this).val());
})
```

(Updated because I was searching for the same thing).